# Entering data into SharePoint lists via Silverlight forms

Tags: development, list, silverlight

Morning all,

Can anyone advise me if it's possible to enter data into a SharePoint list via a Silverlight Application?  if so, are there any basic steps that someone making thier steps into SharePoint Development could follow?

Many thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 1):

There shouldnt be any problem using CSOM ([.NET client API reference for SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193041.aspx))

Example code:

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

// Assume that the web has a list named "Announcements". 
List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements"); 

// We are just creating a regular list item, so we don't need to 
// set any properties. If we wanted to create a new folder, for 
// example, we would have to set properties such as 
// UnderlyingObjectType to FileSystemObjectType.Folder. 
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation(); 
ListItem newItem = announcementsList.Items.Add(itemCreateInfo); 
newItem["Title"] = "My New Item!"; 
newItem["Body"] = "Hello World!"; 
newItem.Update(); 

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

More info could be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179912.aspx

Comment: Sky, appreciate the swift response.  I'll check out the links and get started (+1)